# Boolean changes in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying this code in Python. This gives me a=[False, False], b=[False, False]. But I only want to change b[0], and keep a unchanged.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([True, False])
print(a)
a = b
b[0] = not b[0]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: `a = b` doesn't make a new array. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @MooingRawr: It's a NumPy array, not a list, so treating it like a list won't do the right thing.